# How to add a SimpleRNN layer within Convolutional layers in tensorflow without changing ndim?

Tags: conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to add a RNN layer within a Convolutional layer. Unfortunately due to difference of ndim it's failing to create a model.

Model:

```
model = keras.Sequential(
[
    # layers.Rescaling(1.0/255),
    keras.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="valid", activation='swish'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="swish"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="swish"),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
    layers.Dense(10),
    layers.Dense(2),
    ]
)
```

It'll be really helpful, if someone can help to figure this out :)

**EDIT**

Code that gave the error

```
model = keras.Sequential(
[
    # layers.Rescaling(1.0/255),
    keras.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)),
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="valid", activation='swish'),
    layers.SimpleRNN(512, activation='relu')
    layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="swish"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="swish"),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
    layers.Dense(10),
    layers.Dense(2),
]
)
```

Error Message

```
Input 0 of layer "simple_rnn" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 254, 254, 32)
```

Comment: Where would you like to add the RNN layer?

Comment: I was thinking either to have one RNN layer right after 1st conv layer but I can work with adding  RNN layer after the entire Conv layers and dense layers too.

Comment: Could you add the code that you tried that gave the error? That would make it a lot easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks! I have added the error code and the line that contributed to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a `layers.Reshape` layer before and after the RNN layer, the shape issue is resolved.

```py
model = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)),
        layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding="valid", activation='swish'),
        layers.Reshape((-1, 32)),  # flatten only the two spatial dimensions
        layers.SimpleRNN(512),
        layers.Reshape((16, 16, 2)),  # whatever shape you like
        layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),
        layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="swish"),
        layers.MaxPooling2D(),
        layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="swish"),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
        layers.Dense(10),
        layers.Dense(2),
    ]
)
```

I don't know if it makes sense to use 2d convolution after the RNN layer. I think it might destroy the spatial semantics of the input. Also the RNN layer will have a huge number of weights. That may speak for adding the RNN layer at the end. Reshaping will work there as well, but you will have to add a dimension, instead of flattening one.